# Return a zero value if there is no data found

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a query to pull the number of new clients/week over 3 months. In the weeks where there was no new customers, it doesn't return anything - I would like it to return a zero value. I understand I need to create a table of all the possible weeks. But I am having trouble understanding how to create the table and join it.

```
SELECT distinct COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID) AS "Qty of Quote Lines Won",
MIN(OmpOrderDate) As "WeekStarting"

FROM SalesOrders   
Left Outer Join SALESORDERLINES On OMPSALESORDERID = OMLSALESORDERID 
Left Outer Join QUOTELINES On OMLQUOTEID = QMLQUOTEID And OMLQUOTELINEID = QMLQUOTELINEID 
Left Outer Join QUOTES On QMLQUOTEID = QMPQUOTEID left outer join organizations on dbo.Quotes.qmpCustomerOrganizationID = dbo.Organizations.cmoOrganizationID

WHERE ompOrderDate >= DATEADD(MOnth, -3, GETDATE())
 AND cmocustomerprospectdate >= DATEADD(MOnth, -3, GETDATE())

AND OMLQUOTEID > 1

Group By DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, ompOrderDate),0)
Order by MIN(OmpOrderDate) ASC
```

Thanks in advance!

this returns the results :

Qty of Quote Lines Won     Week Starting

1                           23/04/2020

1                           15/05/2020

2                           19/05/2020

1                           etc

2

Ideally this would look like:

Qty of Quote Lines Won         Week Starting

1                            21/04/2020

0                           28/04/2020

0                           05/05/2020

1                           12/05/2020

etc - many thanks - I'm sorry my formatting is terrible

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't return anything", is it returning `NULL`?

Comment: thank you @S.Serpooshan. It skips that week in the results, not even returning a zero value.

Comment: We need to see sample data and expected results.

Comment: You need to build a week calendar table for the duration you are interested in, if you google it you will find loads of examples.

Comment: If you just copy your data in and format it as code it will look fine (as I did for you before you undid it all - you can always rollback your last edit).

Comment: OK thank you @DaleK

Comment: Join your list of weeks on this expression: `DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, ompOrderDate), 0)` Lots of other answers explain options for creating the list.